# springboot do not use the database

Tags: spring-boot

I have a springboot project, and I will get the informations if the application.properties is empty.

> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

and I configuration datasource in the application.properties,it can run of success.
But I don't want to use the datasource,

How can I successfully run

Comment: Remove the database relevant from the pom file.I can successfully start

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a dependency in your project. If maven, add this to use in memory database.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```